# How to display mysql rows that contain certain data?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in mysql with a row called 'newrelease'. If the item is a new release my form posts it as 'yes' if no 'no'.

How would i display all items that contain the data 'yes'?

$query = "SELECT * FROM movielist ORDER BY newrelease DESC LIMIT 4";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You could filter the data on the PHP side, but that would be a bad idea : it would mean load more data than you need, for nothing...*

The best solution is to **use a `where` clause in your SQL query**, which would then look like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM movielist 
WHERE newrelease = 'yes'
ORDER BY newrelease DESC 
LIMIT 4
```

*Up to you to re-integrate this in your PHP code ;-)*

And, as an example of page that could give you some additionnal informations : [**Where (SQL)** on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_%28SQL%29).

Comment: This is correct but - because I'm OCD - I thought I would mention that the ORDER BY can be removed since we are only allowing a single value for newrelease.  Actually the optimizer might remove it automatically - not quite sure - but I thought I would mention it anyway.

Comment: @malonso : true, it could be removed -- I didn't notice that the `order by` clause was on the same column as the `where` :-(

Answer (score 1):

...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM movielist where newrelease = 'yes' ORDER BY newrelease DESC LIMIT 4";
```